# Keeping a single column static inside a JTable

Tags: java, jtable

Is there a way to keep the first column of a JTable embedded inside a JScrollPane static on scrolling the mouse horizontally.The table contains more than 50 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of this on [this Swing examples site](http://www.crionics.com/products/opensource/faq/swing_ex/JTableExamples1.html).  The author creates two tables, putting one of them in the scrollpane.  They both share the same model.  He then ties their selection logic together.  The full code is available on the page.