# Common scroll bar for two JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have two tables. One table is a fixed column(ie. the table will not have any impact on the scrolling of scrollbar of another table). These two tables have to be commonly scrolled by a vertical scrollbar.Any idea or suggesstion or examples?

This is a continuation of the previous question.
[Fixed Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130082/keeping-a-single-column-static-inside-a-jtable)
The answer for which is here [FixedColumn.java](http://www.crionics.com/products/opensource/faq/swing_ex/src/examples/FixedColumnExample.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fixed Column Table](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/fixed-column-table/) or [Row Number Table](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/) give some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution to this problem. Just put your "fixed column" table into "row header" decoration area of scroll pane used for the second table. it should something like following:

```
JTable table1 = new JTable();
JTable table2 = new JTable();
JScrollPane scrollPane = JScrollPane(table2);

JViewport viewport = new JViewport();
viewport.setView(table1);
viewport.setPreferredSize(table1.getPreferredSize());
scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(viewport);
scrollPane.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER,table1.getTableHeader());
```

You can find more information at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#decorations